# Remove duplicate element from a class list

Tags: c#

How can I eliminate duplication of element "address" from Impinjreader class list as shown below? I'm trying to avoid to connect on multiple copy of an IP address.

```
static List <ImpinjReader> readers = new List <ImpinjReader>();
List<ImpinjReader> DistinctReaders = readers.Distinct().ToList();

public bool Con()
{
    try
    {
      readers.Add(new ImpinjReader(address, ""));

      foreach (ImpinjReader reader in DistinctReaders)
      {
          // From here I am receiving a duplicate ip addresses 
          // assigned with ascending count values inside 
          // DistinctReaders.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about to declare your `DistinctReaders` as `HashSet<ImpinjReader>`? You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `ImpinjReader` to make it work

Comment: Use the overload of [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2) supplying an `IEqualityComparer<ImpinjReader>` that compares the desired elements.  You can do this in the `foreach` if you don't want to change the `DistinctReaders` list.

Comment: Also, after you add an item to `readers`, it will not affect `DistinctReaders` (in the code you have currently). It may be better if you implement `DistinctReaders` as a read-only property that gets the distinct items each time it is called (use `=>` instead of `=`):  `List<ImpinjReader> DistinctReaders => readers?.Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Also, where is `address` defined? It would be helpful to know what type it is. And it would be nice to see the definition of the `ImpinjReader` class (at least the relevant constructor and property)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a distinct list based on the `address` property. The below code groups your objects by `address` and then only grabs the first item in each group before returning a new list.

```
List<ImpinjReader> DistinctReaders = readers.GroupBy(x=>x.address).Select(z=>z.First()).ToList();
```